# django-jinja href not downloading file

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Hey guys I was making a page where people can download my stuff.I made a model of thta and It is succesfull in uploading that but the problem i swhen I click on the download button front end I t doesn,t download that stuff .Instead of that it downloads the copy of the page.

Here,s the models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%M/%d/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here,s the views.py

```
def upload(request):
    upload = Upload()
    return render(request,'app/download.html',{'upload':upload})
```

Here,s the html file

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="download">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="{{upload.image}}" alt="Image containing link to you,r success">
        </p>
    </div>

    <h2>Click on the button below</h2>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="{{upload.file.id}}" download>Yeah do it</a></button>
</div>





{% endblock %}
```

Comment: try href="{{upload.file.url}}"

Comment: let me know if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54923428/3868653) works

Comment: @JibinMathews Now i get a value error

Comment: @UbaidParvez is your issue resolved ?

Comment: you,r answer didn,t worked but then i made it .. Thanks for you,r help

Comment: what changes you made to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="download">
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="{{upload.image}}" alt="Image containing link to you,r success">
        </p>
    </div>

    <h2>Click on the button below</h2>
    <a href="{{upload.file.url}}" class="btn btn-primary">Yeah do it</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Changes explained:

- `{{upload.file.url}}` will give you the url to your uploaded file.
- directly add `"btn btn-primary"` to your anchor tag. It'll display as button. You don't need seperate `<button>` tag